# How do you save an image displayed in Spyder Plots panel programmatically?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, spyder

I have recently attempted to save images in Spyder using the `pyplot.savefig()` command as follows (imported from matplotlib), but it doesn't work:

E.g. code:

```
filename = 'myImage.png'

#images contain the image shown in the Spyder Plots pane
pyplot.imshow(images)

pyplot.savefig(filename)
```

I am aware that the Plots pane has a Save button, but I want to save the image *programmatically* (using Python).

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `plt.imsave()` to save the image. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread('test.png')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.imsave("myImage.png", img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine for single images  But now I am trying to use hstack/vstack to display an image array in pyplot & this method only saves the last image in the array? Is there a way to save exactly what is displayed in pyplot into a single image file programmatically? Thanks!